# How can I determine the number of Python packages available for a specific package name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, python-wheel

Python packages vary in terms of their compatibility with different Python versions and platforms. For example, in the case of "cffi" equals 1.16.0 version packages on PyPI, you can find approximately 51 distinct packages tailored for various Python versions and platforms such as Windows, macOS, and Linux. On the other hand, packages like 'coloredlogs' equals 15.0.1 version offer a single package that works across all platforms and different Python versions.

Is there a way to determine the number of variations available for any Python package with a specific version?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail? How did you produce these numbers in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can find these from the [PyPI JSON API](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json.html).

The distribution `coloredlogs==15.0.1` only provides 2 files, an sdist and a universal wheel:

```
>>> resp = urllib3.request("GET", "https://pypi.org/pypi/coloredlogs/15.0.1/json")
>>> data = resp.json()
>>> len(data["urls"])
2
>>> for dist in data["urls"]:
...     print(dist["filename"])
... 
coloredlogs-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
coloredlogs-15.0.1.tar.gz
```

That package is [pure Python](https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/tree/15.0.1/coloredlogs) source code and doesn't provide any compiled extension modules, so a universal wheel is sufficient.

But for example, with `cffi` 1.16.0 as mentioned in the question, there are many wheels available, built with different [platform compatibility tags](https://peps.python.org/pep-0425/):

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> resp = urllib3.request("GET", "https://pypi.org/pypi/cffi/1.16.0/json")
>>> data = resp.json()
>>> len(data["urls"])
52
```

The actual filenames:

```
>>> for dist in data["urls"]:
...     print(dist["filename"])
... 
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.manylinux_2_17_i686.manylinux2014_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_ppc64le.manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_s390x.manylinux2014_s390x.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-musllinux_1_1_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.manylinux_2_17_i686.manylinux2014_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_ppc64le.manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_s390x.manylinux2014_s390x.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-musllinux_1_1_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.manylinux_2_17_i686.manylinux2014_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_ppc64le.manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_s390x.manylinux2014_s390x.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win32.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.manylinux_2_17_i686.manylinux2014_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_ppc64le.manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_s390x.manylinux2014_s390x.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.manylinux_2_17_i686.manylinux2014_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_ppc64le.manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_s390x.manylinux2014_s390x.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_i686.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-win32.whl
cffi-1.16.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
cffi-1.16.0.tar.gz
```